# TFS - Gated Check - A version override can not be specified on a shelveset build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am using a gated check-in for my TFS server. Everything was working great until today. I now get error message **"A version override can not be specified on a shelveset build"** every time I try and check in a change. Does anyone know why I am getting this error message?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a value specified for the "Get Version" parameter of your build definition?

Comment: Yes there is. That was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the build has been set to get a specific version of the code at build time, rather than the latest. Edit the build definition, go to the "process" tab.

If you're using the default template then expand the "advanced" section and see if there is anything in the "Get Version" setting.

[image: Default template settings]

If you're using the upgrade template then you need to look for the "Msbuild arguments" setting.

[image]

Both of these settings can also be modified when queueing a build, but I'm assuming you're not doing that otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Right on the money. Thanks!